# obtaining information from time vector

Tags: matlab, date, vector

I have a vector of temperatures and a cell array of Date/Time. I want to create 4 variables where each variable represents different stages of the day. For example, I need to create variables for all of the temperatures recorded between 09:00 - 15:00, 15:00-21:00, 21:00-03:00, and 03:00-09:00 for the entire year.

So, if the temperature was recorded hourly for a year I would have 8760 measurements, I would like to break this down into separate variable corresponding to the times shown above.

```
clear all
StartDate = '2011-01-01 00:00';
EndDate = '2011-12-31 23:57';
Resolution = 60;
DateTime=datestr(datenum(StartDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):Resolution/(60*24):...
    datenum(EndDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DateTime=cellstr(DateTime);
data = 1 + (20-1).*rand(8760,1);
```

So, in the end I will have a variable which has the temperatures between those times taken each day for the entire year.

Currently I'm converting DateTime into vectors with datevec and then using:

```
P1{i}( not(  3 <= DateVector(:,4) & DateVector(:,4) < 9 ) ) = nan;
```

to specify the different times of the day. Is this the best method of doing such a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leave your time vector as a simple numeric for as long as possible that is, until you actually need to create a display.

So I would replace:

```
DateTime=datestr(datenum(StartDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):Resolution/(60*24):...
    datenum(EndDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DateTime=cellstr(DateTime);
```

With :

```
DateTime = (datenum(StartDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):Resolution/(60*24):datenum(EndDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
```

And perhaps I would precompute the time, as

```
Time = mod(DateTime,1)
```

Then to find all of the measurements within a certain time of day:

```
%Between 12:00 and 15:00
currentLimits = [12 15]/24;  %Two times in units of days    
mask =Time >=currentLimits(1)  &  Time >=currentLimits(1);
currentTemperatures = data(mask);
```

You could also use date vectors instead of date numbers.  Working with strings is going to be a lot slower, and doesn't really add much value.